# Modify the HttpContent response in the Web API pipeline

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I would like wrap my web api controller response in a generic class and can't work out how to get the actual type from HttpResponseMessage.Content.

e.g. My Controller

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(ApiAuthentication))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostLogOnTest()
    {
        ApiAuthentication loginResponse = new ApiAuthentication();

        return Ok(loginResponse);
    }
```

I need to be able to wrap all the controller response in a 'data' container. I could code this response class into each method but I thought it would be nice to do in common place? So I have a class

```
[DataContract]
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The data.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember(Name="data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

I can hook into a MessageHandler and get the HttpResponseMessage but when I try to get the Content from .Content - it comes as a ObjectContent<> - i just want the ApiAuthentication so i can then create new HttpResponseMessage>

Is there any way to do this or easier way?

Thanks